# Is there any ways to make this code shorter to return object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make this code shorter.

```
 const coupons = rets.map((ret) => ({
  coupon_id: ret.coupon_id,
  bot_id: ret.bot_id,
  lang_cd: ret.lang_cd,
  coupon_name: ret.coupon_name,
  start_date: ret.start_date,
  end_date: ret.end_date,
  coupon_data: ret.coupon_data,
  title: ret.title,
  sub_title: ret.sub_title,
  image: ret.image,
  style: ret.style,
  section: ret.section,
  button_pc: ret.button_pc,
}));
```

I get `rets` from DB.

I tried like below by myself but it didn't work well.
error says like [column is string].

```
const couponColumns = [
  'coupon_id', 'bot_id', 'lang_cd', 'coupon_name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 
  'coupon_data', 'title', 'sub_title',' image', 'style', 'section', 'button_pc'
]

const coupons = rets.map((ret) => ({
   couponColumns.map((column) => {
     column: ret.column
   }
}));
```

Comment: You need bracket notation for the variable property name, and you also need to return an object instead of starting a function block in the nested map

Comment: `const coupons = rets.map((ret) => ({
   couponColumns.map((column) => {
     [column]: ret.column
   }
})); `

Comment: If you have an array of objects with those property names why are you mapping over it to create an array of objects with those same property names?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried     const coupons = rets.map((ret) => ({
      couponColumns.map((column) => {  
        [column]: ret[column]
      })
    })); but it didn't work

Comment: const coupons = rets.map((ret) => ({...ret}));